# Python Unzipping files with different name to a different location

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I am trying to extract the files from a zip archive and appending "EI" to each file inside it. I want these files to be extracted in a certain location. I'm new to python, hence unable to figure out.

```
for i in zip_list:
    if ("Rally-EI" in i):
        zipdata = zipfile.ZipFile(i)
        zipinfos = zipdata.infolist()

        for zipinfo in zipinfos:
            zipinfo.filename = zipinfo.filename[:-4] + "_EI.txt"
            zipdata.extract(zipinfo)
```

This is the code I'm using for appending the file name and it is working well. Need to extract these files to a specific location.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `os.chdir()` to change the current directory temporarily for this extraction. It's not the most efficient way, but, it will do the work.

Do save your current working directory using `os.getcwd()` to revert back to the original working directory after the extraction is done.